# Term for people that cover up scandals due to external interest

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm probably not phrasing the question well, but an example would be:

A person invests in Company A. He/she hears from a source inside Company A that the company is involved in questionable practices that should be reported (but this person has no involvement in these practices). Instead of reporting this, however, the person decides to hide this information due to his/her financial interests in the company.

Comment: This person has a "Vested interest". A modern opposite of a whistleblower is a "NATSA" - not allowed to say anything.

Comment: The person could also be termed as having "insider knowledge".  I expect there's a term for it in the financial world but I haven't as yet found it.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Comment: Thanks tchrist, however I wasn't asking this question because I was trying to solve a word puzzle. I was genuinely interested in knowing if there was an appropriate word that fit this description.

Answer (score 1):

Despite not being directly involved in the original activities, the person is helping cover up the activities and in all probability gaining financially from their continued secrecy. This person has therefore become a *[conspirator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conspirator)*.

Comment: This is the closest to what I was thinking of. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 0):

**sandbagger**

> Noun: **sandbagger**  'san(d),ba-gu(r)
>
> Someone who deceives you about his true nature or intent in order to take advantage of you
>
> Derived forms: sandbaggers
>
> Type of: beguiler, cheat, cheater, deceiver, slicker, trickster

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=sandbagger)

Comment: Thanks Drew, although this isn't quite what I was thinking about. Deception is certainly involved, but arguably the person is being deceptive because he/she is protecting his own self interests, and not necessarily because he/she is actively trying to take advantage of someone else.